# Why does a 'close' link appear on my own question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

I have just noticed that the `close` link is at the bottom of my question. Then I clicked, and a modal dialog appeared asking me why it should be closed. The options are

Duplicate of...

Off-topic because...

Too broad

Primarily opinion-based

and so on. How come do I know if my question is like one of the listed reasons?

Why do I want to close my question? Why do I think that my question is off-topic or something else? Even if so how do I see that?

I mean how can I say that my question is needed to be closed?

Comment: It is always there unless its locked or closed.

Comment: It all works in the same way as for the questions of others. You ask something, keep looking for a solution, and find a canonical duplicate you didn't find before. Or you realize that the question you ask doesn't have the "easy" solution you think it had, and find it "too broad" as a result, etc. etc. In such a case you can help to vote appropriately.

Comment: **[Help Center > Privileges > view close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)**: "This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions." See also: [Etiquette for closing your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions) at MSE

Answer (score 3):

You can close your own question if you find that it meets any of those criteria. You may have comments that tell you why your question may have been downvoted, so you can close your question because you agree with one or more of the comments. Or you may not be getting an answer, so you decide to close it and ask a new question that addresses your problem better.

See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: ...or (and this seems more likely) you've asked a duplicate question that you didn't find when you originally posted, but now that it's been pointed out you agree that your question is, indeed, a duplicate.

Comment: can't you just delete your question then?

Comment: @Bolu: Sometimes it is appropriate to delete it, but beware of running into a question-ban. Sometimes it is a **good** question, but still a **duplicate** question, so it should stay. Other times there are already good and/or upvoted answers, so that's impossible.

Comment: @Deduplicator, will closed questions get deleted eventually?

Comment: @Bolu: See here: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: @Bolu it depends, you can delete your question if your question dosen't have upvotes or answers, but if unfortunatly, if someone answered or someone upvoted you can't delete your question anymore. It happen to me, i was kind of frustrated so i had no choice but to vote for closing my own question...

Answer (score 1):

The logical way would be to just delete your question once you realize it should be closed for some reason : (Typo, comment that shows you a duplicate)

But if your question has an upvoted answer (for example) and you can't delete it anymore, you can at least participate in closing your own question. It's one of the reasons why it comes along with the privilege.