# Should the user be allowed to flag his own question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I tried to flag my own question and was able to proceed. I think that must not be allowed.

Comment: I've voted to close my own question quite a few times in the past. Those who do not have the privilege to vote to close can only flag, so flagging makes sense in this case IMO.

Comment: If you tried to flag your own question, then you must have had a reason, correct?

Comment: We also have delete functionality, dont we ????????

Comment: Not always, Neji, and that's not the only reason to flag either.

Comment: @Neji Often the system does not allow you to delete a question (e.g. has answer with >= 1 score), and often you just want to close the question rather than delete (e.g. it is informative, but off-topic).

Comment: i personally think, close votes and flagging must only be used by visitors and not by the one who posts question!!!

Comment: Neji, you don't have to flag/close something that you don't want to, but negating that ability from others don't make much sense. I do what I believe to be right, and closing/deleting a post is often the right thing, even when I'm the author of such post.

Comment: why will people upvote anything thats not related with the site's objective. Also there are moderators for the purpose, in such a case moderation must go through this case.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are **moderated by the community** (mainly). Diamond moderators will step in mostly when the community can't sort it out.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes and i am not suggesting to negating that ability, bt yes from the owner itself coz owner has other privileges than the visitors

Comment: P.s. you might want to extend your question with a motivation. At the moment it's just a statement.

Comment: Yep, without a real motivation you're just taking away an useful feature for no real reason.

Comment: Neji, I don't think changing your question title from "flagging" to "vote close" will make much sense with the comments and answers so far. I believe it would be more appropriate to make a new question, explaining your motivation behind it.

Comment: And to follow up on what @FabrícioMatté says, then it would probably be a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258617/why-close-link-appears-on-my-own-question But please roll back this question. You've fundamentally changed it, rendering my answer invalid, which really is a no go.

Comment: @Bart or we could engage in a rollback war with Neji, and he would then find the need to flag his question for moderator attention. `</joke>`

Answer (score 11):

Sure. If anything to notify moderators of a situation you can't deal with yourself. Say the comments get somewhat out of hand, yet you can't remove them. Or a comment stream simply becomes entirely obsolete. Or someone keeps editing your question to a point where it's no longer what you're trying to ask. Or... well, you get the point.

There certainly are situations in which case it's best to flag and have someone deal with a situation you can't easily handle yourself. Perhaps you might not flag it as spam, offensive, or low quality, but that doesn't mean the dialogue should go.

Comment: By the way, you can also flag specific comments. Though flagging a question for moderator attention is also valid. Edit wars are a valid point which I've almost forgot, +1

Comment: and also we do have powers to flag a comment, and whenever anybody edits a question, it is cleared after a round of moderation. Moderators have ample powers to justify their decision, so i personally all powers justify most scenarios, still flagging your own question to delete, that must not be given, if you want to put it to moderators attention you can flag it either way!!!!

Comment: As Bart said: with comment wars it is best to flag the question / answer they are under since the mods get a better view then.

Comment: It's often better and easier to just flag the question rather than flag individual comments when it's really multiple comments that need to be taken care of. But even disregarding that, there is no problem with users having an option that's essentially *"something is going on with this question that needs an action I can't take"*. It's a very useful feature in many occasions and not a problem. If you think there is a problem that's caused by the feature, explicitly state so in your question, because I don't see it.

Comment: @Neji: as said: there are situations in which you can't delete the question, so you should still be able to flag it.

Comment: even flag has an option of " needs moderator attention " , then why do keep delete button available to the author ??

Comment: To allow the user to delete the question when that's still possible? What's your point here?